# Change the path needed for UIRefreshControl to go to UIControlEventValueChanged

Tags: ios, uiview, ios6, uiscrollview, uirefreshcontrol

I'm trying to add the `UIRefreshControl` to my `UIScrollView`, but the problem is that it's area is too small, so it's almost impossible for user to pull to the required level.

So is there a way to trigger the state of this control or change the length of the required pull gesture?

I know, that this control is new and there may be no straight way of achieving this, but maybe someone has found a hack?

Comment: Similar concept: http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/pull-to-refresh-tableview

Comment: @mrunal i just wanted to us built-in solution for that

Comment: Then refer this: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/ios-app-builder/ios-6-best-practices-introducing-the-uirefreshcontrol/314

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found a solution: make a delegate of your scrollView and in `- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate` refresh the control at some offset

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
  if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < -70) {
    [refreshControl beginRefreshing];
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
       [self handleRefresh:refreshControl];
     });
  }
}
```

Dispatch is made for not lagging the interface while getting info from server.
If you then update something in your UI, use `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{//update UI code});`

Comment: @XhackerLiu that async